# how to edit items of radio button Group?

Tags: android, list, dialog, radio-button

I have a fragment. In that I have a List - named Stops. That carries 3 stops- patia, SAILASHREE, niladri Vihar. The 3 stops are shown on a radiogroup. I make a selection from that list of radio buttons. I select SAILAHREE and I click on EDIT button. Now the dialog box is launched. There I edit "SAILASHREE" to "sailashree vihar". When I press yes, the text on the screen is not changed from SAILASHREE to sailashree vihar.

Before: Radio Group:
patia
SAILASHREE
niladri vihar

After:
patia
sailashree vihar
SAILASHREE
niladri vihar

Needed:
patia
sailashree vihar
niladri vihar

code:

```
public class PlusOneFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    static Context cntxt ;
    static List<String> Stops;
    static int count_stops;
    Button Edit, Add, Delete, Up, Bottom;
    String DialogResult;
    static StopActivity obj;
    public PlusOneFragment(Context c, int count_stopsArg, List<String>  StopsArg, StopActivity Arg) {
        // Required empty public constructor
        cntxt = c;
        count_stops = count_stopsArg;
        Stops = StopsArg;
        obj = Arg;
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PlusOneFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PlusOneFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PlusOneFragment fragment = new PlusOneFragment(cntxt, count_stops, Stops, obj);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        //TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seat_serial_prefix);
        //tv.setText("yourText");
        Edit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit) ;
        Add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add) ;
        Delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete) ;
        Up = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_up) ;
        Bottom = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_bottom) ;
        Up.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Bottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        // layout params to use when adding each radio button
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // add 20 radio buttons to the group
        for (int u = 0; u < count_stops; u++) {
            RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(cntxt);
            String label = Stops.get(u);
            newRadioButton.setText(label);
            newRadioButton.setId(u);
            radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
        }
        Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
                int a = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                DialogResult = Stops.get(a);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(cntxt);
                alertDialog.setTitle("PASSWORD");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Password");

                final EditText input = new EditText(cntxt);
                input.setText(DialogResult);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                alertDialog.setView(input);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            DialogResult = input.getText().toString();
                            Stops.set(a, DialogResult);
                            radiogroup.removeViewAt(a);
                            RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(cntxt);
                            String label = DialogResult;
                            newRadioButton.setText(label);
                            newRadioButton.setId(a);
                            radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton,a);

                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code for `fragment_first` and any other related layout files? Because from the initial look it seems like the problem is you are adding a new view  `radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton,a); ` here. That's why you are getting that output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

I have comments at places 1) and 2) for the changes I made.

```
Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // 1)  No need to do the findview here
                
//                RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
                int a = radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                DialogResult = Stops.get(a);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(cntxt);
                alertDialog.setTitle("PASSWORD");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Password");

                final EditText input = new EditText(cntxt);
                input.setText(DialogResult);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                alertDialog.setView(input);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // 2) just get the view from that radio group and set new
                                // text to it. No need to remove and add view.
                                DialogResult = input.getText().toString();
                                Stops.set(a, DialogResult);
                                ((RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(a)).setText(DialogResult);
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.show();
            }

        });
```